# how to calculate network sync status - Logical discussion

Tags: algorithm, routes, logic

Let me explain:

I am making a network routing protocol analyze function

I get line for NODE 1 saying

```
2->4 4->4 5->4 6->6
```

Meaning to get to 2 go to 4, to get to 4 go to 4, to go to 5 go to 4...

I also hove "god view" of the topology

And now for the Question :) :

How should i calculate the sync % of a node?

```
1) goodChoices/allNeededPaths (if both 0 then sync=1)
2) goodChoices/allmychoices * badOrMissingChoices/allNeededPaths 
3) what is your idea
```

Problems that need to think about

If god view is NONE-CONNECTED but in my NODE topology i see  `4->4 5->4` what % should i right?

Comment: For me personally, the question is unclear. I would recommend to reformat the question in more readable way, and maybe reorder the sentences you have.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is a matter of opinion and/or of requirements. There is no universal definition of "percentage synchronized" other than how your requirements define it.